# MySQL views where a column is NULL

Tags: mysql, null, view, mysql-workbench

My headache has begun since Ive tried to make this MySQL view, where the outcome value for one of the columns is NULL. I need to have a real value like 0 instead.

I take my id from table1 and compare it in table2, so its not sure that there is a number with that id, if there is no number in table2 the value will turn up NULL and that where i need 0 instead. Here goes my code for the view:

```
CREATE VIEW `instock` AS
SELECT 
    table1.name AS name,
    table1.supl AS supply,
    table2.num AS numbers,
    table1.maxnum AS maxnumbers
FROM
    (table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON ((table1.id = table2.id)))
ORDER BY table1.name
```

Its the column numbers where i have a NULL value

Comment: Try `coalesce(table2.num, 0) as numbers`. [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) will then return `0` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: thanks, I have never heard of that command but it sure did the trick! This topic is resolved

Comment: Another option would be [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull): i.e. `IFNULL(table2.num, 0) as numbers`.

Comment: oh, now my question seems silly.. i thought IFNULL was only in case or procedures. thanks for the enlightment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your `left join` in the query. A `left join` gives *all* rows from the *left* table (`table1`) including those for which there's no counterpart in the other table (`table2`). For these unmatched rows from the right table you will get NULL for all `table2`'s columns, including `table2.num`.

*Perhaps* you are looking for an `inner join`. It depends on your data and whether your `table2.num` is NULLable. To just replace the NULLs with zeroes, use either [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

```
CREATE VIEW `instock` AS
SELECT 
    table1.name AS name,
    table1.supl AS supply,
    COALESCE(table2.num,0) AS numbers,
    table1.maxnum AS maxnumbers
FROM
    (table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON ((table1.id = table2.id)))
ORDER BY table1.name
```

Or [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

```
CREATE VIEW `instock` AS
SELECT 
    table1.name AS name,
    table1.supl AS supply,
    IFNULL(table2.num,0) AS numbers,
    table1.maxnum AS maxnumbers
FROM
    (table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON ((table1.id = table2.id)))
ORDER BY table1.name
```

If you want to completely skip items from `table2` that are not in `table1` (wrt. the ID field), you could use an `inner join`:

```
CREATE VIEW `instock` AS
SELECT 
    table1.name AS name,
    table1.supl AS supply,
    table2.num AS numbers,
    table1.maxnum AS maxnumbers
FROM
    (table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON ((table1.id = table2.id)))
ORDER BY table1.name
```

Again: It depends on your needs. IFNULL/COALESCE will show `0` instead of NULL, INNER JOIN will skip the lines completely.

(When in doubt, I always refer to [this explanation on joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins). It's worth a mint.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ifnull** function:

```
SELECT 
  table1.name AS name,
  table1.supl AS supply,
  ifnull(table2.num,0) AS numbers,
  table1.maxnum AS maxnumbers
FROM
  (table1
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON ((table1.id = table2.id)))
ORDER BY table1.name
```